# AngularJS ngMessages can't bind to $index expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am building an Angular form that needs repeatable form elements inside an `ngRepeat`.

```
<form name="form">
    <div ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4]">
      <input name="something_{{$index}}" ng-model="hi" required>
      <div ng-messages="form.something_{{$index}}.$error">
        <ng-message="required">This is required</ng-message>
      </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{form | json: 4}}</pre>
  </form>
```

Angular now supports dynamically declared `input` names so that you don't have to do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4] ng-form="repeated-form"></div>
```

And you can use `{{$index}}` inside the `ngRepeat` to declare items dynamically. But this doesn't seem to work with `ngMessages`, which throws an error when I try to bind the index into it.

i.e. this:

```
<div ng-messages="form.something_{{$index}}.$error">
```

throws this:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 16 of the expression [form.something_{{$index}}.$error] starting at [{{$index}}.$error].
```

How can we dynamically declare which property on the form to watch, if ng-messages can't watch the form value that is declared with its {{$index}}?

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/4oOasbtffTgKqmxcppUG?p=preview (check console)

Comment: have you tried `ng-messages="form.something_$index.$error"` - just remove the `{{ }}`

Comment: Thanks for the response. That would be awesome! But it isn't properly interpolated. The end result html is ```<div ng-messages="form.something_$index.$error">```

Comment: Try this `<div ng-messages="form['something_'+$index].$error">`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, the result is the same! :-(  ```Syntax Error: Token '[' is not a valid identifier```

Comment: ngBind (the {{ }} directive) executes at the same priority as ngMessages. That means that ngMessages might be processed before ngBind for the element (so ngMessages execution code will still see the untransformed {{expr}} text.

Comment: This is malformed HTML: `<ng-message="required">` change it something like `<div ng-message="required"></div>` http://plnkr.co/edit/rBOgjsdaBW8sgipX7AWl?p=preview

Comment: Sorry. Please see this updated PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/4oOasbtffTgKqmxcppUG?p=preview

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
ng-messages="form['something_' + $index].$error"
```

Should work. I generally wouldn't put {{ }} in any of the ng directives because most of the ng directives execute with priority level 0 (including the {{ }} directive, ngBind). Also, the ng directives all use $evaluate on their argument, so they look at variable values in the scope by default.

Priority 0 for multiple directives on the same element means that Angular can't guarantee which directive will be applied first. Because of that, it is generally best to avoid using ngDirectives together as behavior can vary. ngIf is an exception as it executes with priority 600 (which is why directives aren't evaluated for an ng-if element not currently in the DOM no matter what).

Comment: Hi Tahsis—it doesn't appear to be working with this method here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4oOasbtffTgKqmxcppUG?p=preview
Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fEIoKFkqkh8YqKDf03C8?p=preview I believe this is working (it shows required messages).

Answer (score 8):

```
    <div ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3]">
      <input name="something_{{$index}}" ng-model="hi" required>
      <div ng-messages="form['something_' + $index].$error">
        <ng-message="required">This is required</ng-message>
      </div>
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/k5nzkpkJwSuf5dvlMMZi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but it's not being interpolated correctly. Feel free to try in the Plnkr.

Comment: What do you mean? Everything works fine in example plunkr

Comment: Added ```ng-maxlength``` so that it is clear that it is not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/4oOasbtffTgKqmxcppUG?p=preview. As you can see, the ```$index``` is not interpolated

Comment: Thanks Deblaton. I suppose I was under the impression that $index would be interpolated into the HTML and that I would see the index number. When I looked at it and saw $index, I assumed it wasn't working. Wrapped my head around it now. Thanks a bunch!