# Validate a dynamic form and Show ngMessages with ngRepeat and dynamic names

Tags: angularjs, forms, dynamic, names

I have a form with a email field and a button a button which creates a new email fields with a dynamic name.

so i used a ngRepeat with a dynamic name:

```
<div class="emailReceiverContent" ng-repeat="i in getNb()" > 
<input class="textInput" 
       ng-init="fieldName = 'mailReciever' + i"
       name="{{fieldName}}"
       ng-model="requestedInfos.mailReceivers[i]"
       type="email"
       required />

<div class="errorMessage" ng-messages="emailForm[fieldName].$error"          
       role="alert" ng-show="submitted">
       <div ng-messages-include="error-messages"></div>
</div>


 <p class="help-block" ng-show="emailForm['mailReciever'+[i]].$invalid">
       Valid Email Address Required<br/>
       {{emailForm['mailReciever'+[i]].$error}}
 </p>
```

...
Each time the current field shows the error messages, 
when i create the second , the first one is not changing anymore.

when i submit my form it should show the error message and i have only the errors for the last field.

How it is possible to get the errors for each field separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS ngMessages can't bind to $index expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863720/angularjs-ngmessages-cant-bind-to-index-expression)